# need help checking dates using strtotime()

Tags: php

I have a function that will check to see if someones status is a certain value and if it is and after a year of it, that persons status will be updated.

Here is the code

```
if (strtotime($csvstatuschange) < strtotime("-365 day") && (
        $csvstatus == "Non-Active, Unable to Monitor - Incidental Business use Exclusion" ||
        $csvstatus == "Non-Active - Insurance Cancelled" ||
        $csvstatus == "Non-Active - Employee Not Covered Under Listed Policy" ||
        $csvstatus == "Non-Active - No Longer Employed" ||
        $csvstatus == "Non-Active - Other"
)) {
    $status = "Archived";
    $wsth = $DBH->prepare("
        UPDATE csvdata 
        SET status = :status, 
            statuschangedate = :date 
        WHERE username = :username
    ");
    $wsth->execute(array(
        ':status' => $status, 
        ':username' => $csvusername, 
        ':date' => $date
    ));
}
```

So my issue is - for instance if the persons status is `Non-Active - Insurance Cancelled` and it was changed today.  There status still gets changed.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: have you try to print value of `stsrtotime($csvstatuschange)` and `strtotime("-365 day");`

Comment: I suggest you to try [dateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: No I'll see what I get when i print the values, one sec.  diEcho why use dateinterval?

Comment: Because it is fit for your need.

Comment: Can you give some code? and its not printing anything but it is executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems most likely that `$csvstatuschange` is in a format that `strtotime` can't make sense of. As a result it's returning `false`, which is cast to integer `0`. `0` will always be less than 1 year ago.

Make sure that the format is one that can be read by `strtotime`. My preference is `Y-m-d H:i:s` since it's unambiguous. A format like `d/m/Y` can be ambiguous because `m/d/Y` is also frequently used (is `3/4/95` the fourth of March or the third of April?)

Comment: Yeah, that's ambiguous due to the thing I mentioned. Can you change the format? If not, you might have to split up the string, or use [`date_create_from_format`](http://php.net/date-create-from-format)

Comment: Ya I can change the format at the beginning to how it should be....what should i change it to because i am using `date("n-j-Y");`

Comment: If you're using `date()`, are you passing a second parameter? If so, just use that parameter instead of `strtotime()`.

Comment: Here I switched the format to y-m-d and it seems to work.  I got no error and it did not change status automatically.  The date is accessed from server than checked using strtotime().